# Upload Large File by PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, server

Here is my phpinfo()

https://devmail.equidesk.com/phpinfo.php

I can't upload more than 2MB file by php.
I increased upload limit in php.ini but it's not working.

Comment: Change the values of post_max_size and upload_max_filesize and restart apache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload large files and Time out php uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069439/time-out-php-uploads)

Answer (score 1):

see this:
[Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

you should change php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M

post_max_size = 10M
```

And if you use nginx, should change nginx.conf file

like this.

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    //other lines...
}
```

If you changed server configurations, you should restart fpm and nginx.

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Value of your `upload_max_filesize`  attribute is `2M`. Thats why you are unable to upload more than `2M`.

You need to increase size of `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` file. After that you will be able to upload large file.

You can change it to `128M` or `256M` whatever you want depends upon size of your upload file.

Answer (score 0):

upload_max_filesize in phpinfo still showing 2M

Change this and restart server

```
post_max_size = 250M 
upload_max_filesize = 250M 
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000  
memory_limit = 1000M
```