# ajax gives 503 Service Unavailable error while uploading files greater than 10mb on the server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

Ajax gives 503 Service Unavailable error while uploading files greater than 10mb on the server but it uploads files less than 10mb successfully, It works well on my local server on my computer but it gives this error on my host server, I've tried editting my  MultiPHP INI Editor  file on my domain server I set

```
max_input_time to -1, 
upload_max_file_size to 800mb
```

but it still gives me the same error

I've searched all over the internet I couldn't find the solution, please help me resolve this, thanks.

Comment: *'I've searched all over the internet"* - I doubt that. --- *"I've tried editting my php.ini file on my server I set max_input_time to -1, upload_max_file_size to 800mb":* - Did you restart everything after making those changes?

Comment: There’s another very important setting, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: Did you also check `post_max_size` and `memory_limit` assuming you are going for `upload_max_file_size = 800M` then you want to make `post_max_size = 900M` and `memory_limit=1G`

Comment: thanks for answering my question, please how do I restart my server on my host

Answer (score 0):

There is already a good answer for the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52069476/3429562).

> Go to `php.ini` file and change value with respect to your
> requirements.
>
> **upload_max_filesize**
>
> By default this value is 2M. We need to increase it to the maximum
> size of single file that we want to upload.
>
> **max_input_time**
>
> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse
> input data, like `POST` and `GET`. Timing begins at the moment PHP is
> invoked at the server and ends when execution begins. This would
> include populating `$_FILES superglobal`.
>
> **memory_limit**
>
> This sets the amount of memory a PHP script is allowed to use during
> its execution. Set this to a value greater than ‘`post_max_size`’ so
> that PHP script can load and process the uploaded file.
>
> **post_max_size**
>
> It defines the maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept. This
> value should be greater than ‘`upload_max_filesize`’.
>
> **max_execution_time**
>
> The time a script is allowed to run after its input has been parsed.
> This would include any processing of the file itself.
>
> If you are getting memory related error then turn off the output
> buffering, the PHP configuration directive to be considered is
> “`output_buffering`”
>
> ```
> output_buffering = Off
> ```

One thing I would like to add is to double check if the changes you made to the configuration file are live. To do that you can use the [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function which will return all the configuration values in the current environment.

If the changes are not live, make sure to restart the server and/or check if you edited the correct .ini file which is also mentioned in the phpinfo output.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i've edditted it in the  MultiPHP INI Editor file in my host domain, but it's still giving me the same error 503 Service Unavailable